# Ember rootURL in templates

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to migrate my app away from baseURL to rootURL router configuration. I am stuck determining which url to use for images stored in public/assets in my templates.

Before I was using `assets/images/myimage.png`, now I want to do something like `{{rootURL}}assets/images/myimage.png`, but injecting it from the route seems rather hacky.

```js
setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.controllerFor('application').set('rootURL', this.get('router.rootURL'));
}
```

Is there an established way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can import it like `import config from 'app-name/config/environment'` and use it like `config.rootURL`

Comment: This seems more elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import it like `import config from 'app-name/config/environment'` and use it like `config.rootURL`